# Working with tuples in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

I want to do something like this (simplified quite heavily):

```
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)).zipped map (_ + _)
```

Ignore the actual values of the integers (although it's important that these are 6-tuples, actually :)).  Essentially, I want to use this fairly regularly in a function which maintains a `Map[String, (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)]` when an existing element is updated.

As it is, Scala spits this out at me:

```
<console>:6: error: could not find implicit value for parameter w1: ((Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)) => scala.collection.TraversableLike[El1,Repr1]
   ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)).zipped
```

If I use `Seq`s instead of tuples, everything works fine, but I want to enforce an arity of 6 in the type system (I'll probably `type Record = (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)` as a quick refactor shortly).

Can anyone offer some advice on what I'm doing wrong/why Scala won't deal with the code above?  I thought it might work if I used a 2- or 3-arity tuple, seeing as Scala defines `Tuple2` and `Tuple3`s (I understand that scaling tuple functions across an arbitrary n-arity is difficult), but I get the same error.

Thanks in advance for any help offered :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only want to map over tuples which have identical types--otherwise the map wouldn't make sense--but Tuple doesn't contain that in its type signature.  But if you're willing to do a little work, you can set it up so that tuples work the way you requested:

Groundwork:

```
class TupTup6[A,B](a: (A,A,A,A,A,A), b: (B,B,B,B,B,B)) {
  def op[C](f:(A,B)=>C) = ( f(a._1,b._1), f(a._2,b._2), f(a._3,b._3), 
                            f(a._4,b._4), f(a._5,b._5), f(a._6,b._6) )
}
implicit def enable_tuptup6[A,B](ab: ((A,A,A,A,A,A),(B,B,B,B,B,B))) = {
  new TupTup6(ab._1,ab._2)
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> ((1,2,3,4,5,6) , (6,5,4,3,2,1)) op { _ + _ }
res0: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) = (7,7,7,7,7,7)
```

Comment: I like this.  I need to look into implicits more, as it looks like they're a very powerful construct which I'm missing out on (I'm learning Scala as I go currently).  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I received this little inspiration.

```
class TupleZipper[T <: Product](t1: T) {
  private def listify(p: Product) = p.productIterator.toList
  def zipWith(t2: T) = (listify(t1), listify(t2)).zipped
}
implicit def mkZipper[T <: Product](t1: T) = new TupleZipper(t1)

// ha ha, it's arity magic
scala> ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) zipWith ((6, 5, 4, 3, 2))                      
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
 required: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
       ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) zipWith ((6, 5, 4, 3, 2))
                                     ^

scala> ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) zipWith ((6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1))                   
res1: (List[Any], List[Any])#Zipped[List[Any],Any,List[Any],Any] = scala.Tuple2$Zipped@42e934e

scala> res1 map ((x, y) => x.asInstanceOf[Int] + y.asInstanceOf[Int])      
res2: List[Int] = List(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)
```

Yes, a bunch of Anys comes out the other end.  Not real thrilling but not a lot you can do when you try to force yourself on Tuples this way.

Edit: oh, and of course the type system gives you the full monty here.

```
scala> ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) zipWith ((6, 5, 4, 3, 2, "abc"))         
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("abc")
 required: Int
       ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) zipWith ((6, 5, 4, 3, 2, "abc"))
                                                     ^
```

Comment: It definitely shows the need for a fixed-size homogeneous collection.  Now if we can just encode the number of elements as a peano number in the collection type... (http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/11/practical-church-numerals-in-scala.html).  Total overkill for this problem though!

Answer (score 5):

```
import scala.collection._

type Record = (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)

implicit def toIterable(r: Record) = new Iterable[Int]{
  def iterator = r.productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Int]]
}

implicit def cbf[From <: Iterable[Int]] = new generic.CanBuildFrom[From, Int, Record] {
    def apply(from: From) = apply
    def apply = new mutable.Builder[Int, Record] {
      var array = Array.ofDim[Int](6)
      var i = 0

      def +=(elem: Int) = {
        array(i) += elem
        i += 1
        this
      } 

      def clear() = i = 0

      def result() = (array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3), array(4), array(5))

    }
}
```

usage:

```
scala> ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)).zipped.map{_ + _}
res1: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) = (7,7,7,7,7,7)
```

Answer (score 4):

short solution:

```
type Record = (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)

implicit def toList(r: Record) = r.productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[Int]].toList
implicit def toTuple(l: List[Int]): Record = (l(0), l(1), l(2), l(3), l(4), l(5))
```

usage:

```
scala> ((1,2,3,4,5,6), (6,5,4,3,2,1)).zipped map {_ + _}: Record
res0: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) = (7,7,7,7,7,7)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Very short and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Tuple2#zipped won't help you out here, it works when the contained elements are TraversableLike/IterableLike - which Tuples aren't.

You'll probably want to define your own sumRecords function that takes two Records and returns their sum:

```
def sumRecord(a:Record, b:Record) = new Record(
  a._1 + b._1,
  a._2 + b._2,
  a._3 + b._3,
  a._4 + b._4,
  a._5 + b._5,
  a._6 + b._6
)
```

Then to use it with a Pair[Record, Record]:

```
val p : Pair[Record, Record] = ...
val summed = sumRecord(p._1, p._2)
```

Sure, there are abstractions available; but as Record is going to be fixed throughout your design, then they have little value.

Comment: That's a reasonably clean solution, I guess.  I might wait a bit before accepting this answer in case something more in-line with what I was gunning for comes up, but that would definitely work :).  I was hoping to just use map/sum/zip to do it, as that seems cleaner to me.  Do you know the reasoning for not allowing zip to work on tuples?

Comment: It's because Tuple2.zipped delegates to the collection in _1, and a Tuple isn't a collection.  It should be possible in theory, but for almost every imaginable use you'd be better off using proper collections.

Comment: It's because Record is central to the design that it is worth insisting on having a handful of utility method.

Comment: Ah, I see Kevin, that makes sense.  I'm still learning Scala, so some of the syntax is still reasonably alien to me (hence, trying to look at the source isn't much help, sadly).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can now easily achieve this with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), this way:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val b = (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

object sum extends Poly1 {
  implicit def f = use((t: (Int, Int)) => t._1 + t._2)
}

val r = a.zip(b) map sum // r is a (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
```

The drawback is the weird syntax you have to use to express the `sum` function, but everything is type-safe and type-checked.

Comment: I love this solution, because in an evolving project the tuple size could be changed over time and the once-written code stays unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

As update to Rex Kerr answer, starting from Scala 2.10 you can use [implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html): syntactic sugar that makes that solution even shorter.

```
implicit class TupTup6[A,B](x: ((A,A,A,A,A,A),(B,B,B,B,B,B))) {
   def op[C](f:(A,B)=>C) = ( 
       f(x._1._1,x._2._1),
       f(x._1._2,x._2._2), 
       f(x._1._3,x._2._3),
       f(x._1._4,x._2._4), 
       f(x._1._5,x._2._5), 
       f(x._1._6,x._2._6) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you treat the tuple as a collection.

Is it possible for you to use lists instead of tuples? Then the calculation is simple:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).zip(List(1,2,3,4,5,6)).map(x => x._1 + x._2 )     
res6: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to use lists (`Seq` creates lists by default) because then I can't check in the type system that the records are of length 6; I'm forced to do that at runtime which is something I want to avoid.  Thanks though :).